# django-respite create object

Tags: django, rest

I'm trying to use [django-respite](https://django-respite.readthedocs.org) with Django, but I have problems with the creation of new objects.

While in a normal Django view I would have

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/posts/")
        else:
            form = PostForm()

    ctx = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('app_post/new_post.html', ctx, RequestContext(request))
```

I tried to port it into respite (the doc talks only about GET methods) and I came out with this:

```
# views.py
class PostViews(Views):
    supported_formats = ['html', 'json']
    template_path     = 'post/'

    def index(self, request):    
        ...

    def show(self, request, id):
        ...

    def create(self, request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("posts/")

        return self._render(
            request = request,
            template = 'new_post',
            context = {
                'form': form
            },
       )

    def new(self, request):
        form = PostForm()

        return self._render(
            request = request,
            template = 'new_post',
            context = {
                'form': form
            },
    )


# urls.py
urlpatterns = resource(
    prefix = 'posts/',
    views = PostViews,
    routes = [
        routes.route(
             regex = r'^(?:$|index%s$)' % (templates.format),
             view = 'index',
             method = 'GET',
             name = 'posts'
        ),
        routes.route(
             regex = r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)%s$' % (templates.format),
             view = 'show',
             method = 'GET',
             name = 'post'
        ),
        # New
        routes.route(
             regex = r'^(?:$|new%s$)' % (templates.format),
             view = 'new',
             method = 'GET',
             name = 'post_new'
        ),
        # Create
        routes.route(
             regex = r'^(?:$|create%s$)' % (templates.format),
             view = 'create',
             method = 'POST',
             name = 'post_create'
        )])
```

But when I try to go to

```
http://localhost:8000/posts/new.html
```

I get

```
'PostViews' object has no attribute 'new'
```

Someone can explain me how to manage POST and forms with respite?

Comment: What kind of request are you sending to `http://localhost:8000/projects/new.html` — GET or POST?

Comment: Hi Johannes, I'm sending a GET request

Comment: Alright. Am I right in assuming that you have a typo in your question and that your route prefix is actually `projects/` and not `posts/`, or the other way around?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the question, we are talking only of `posts`, so the prefix is `posts/` (I edited the question, thanks for noticing).
However I don't get why I get this error...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not related but I just wanted to make sure. I'm not sure why you're getting an error, either; the code looks perfectly fine to me. I'll try to reproduce this, though.